# FreeNas running on ESXi - sometimes gets very slugish

Tags: freebsd, vmware-esxi, truenas, vmware-tools

I have a ESXi server (dual quad core, 8GB of DDR3 ram, 6x 1TB WD Blacks running in RAid 5 on the PErc 6/i controller.

I have a 64bit freenas VM running, on this VM I keep about 200Gigs of stuff that my windows machines access.

every now and then the throughput of this VM just dies, for example right now it can't even handle streaming a song and when I tried to transfer a folder the speed goes from 10-400KB/s.

Might I add at this point that the ESXi box has dual gigabit network cards plugged into a good solid gigabit switch and other linux and windows VM's are just fine I have seen speeds over 90MB/s (frequently)

The server still has ram left over (plenty actually) and cpu is very low (500-1000mhz)

any ideas what could cause this?

thanks.

Luc

Comment: Anything in the FreeNAS logs when it slows down like this?   Also, are you connecting via FTP, CIFS, or something else?

Comment: I don't see anything in the system log, just a few normal items. I am using CIFS. the VM itself has 1GB of ram and access to 2 physical Cores (the server has 2x Intel 5520's) so it has plenty of power to serve up a few mp3's :)

Comment: it has nothing to do with networking, if you read my post you will see that I noted that I get speeds of over 90MB/s from other VM's on the same server and that the server is connected with 2x 1gigabit network adapters. you can't get 90MB/s with a 10/100.

Comment: If you haven't done so, under CIFS set the log level to 'Debug' and save/restart the CIFS service.  Try another file transfer and then post the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version of freenas now comes with openvm tools and so far it has been way better. I have not had any problems with related to this qustion.